# Show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of closed squares

Tags: general-topology

I am looking to prove the following. Let $Q = [0,1]\times [0,1]$, then I want to show $$\mathbb{R}^{2} \cong \bigg(\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}Q \times \lbrace k\rbrace\bigg) \big/\sim$$ Where the edges of a square are each equivalent of one edge of four other squares. Essentially, I am trying to tile squares to fill all of the plane. I don't really know how to go about setting up the equivalence relation though, possibly spiralling from the origin outwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the spaces  $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z^2}}Q \times \lbrace k\rbrace$ and $\bigcup_{(k,k’)\in \mathbb{Z^2}}Q \times  (k,k’)$ are homeomorphic and $$\mathbb{R}^{2} \cong \bigg(\bigcup_{(k,k’)\in \mathbb{Z^2}}Q \times (k,k’)\bigg) \big/\sim,$$ where $(x,x’,k,k’)\sim (y,y’,l,l’)$ iff $x+k=y+l$ and $x’+k’=y’+l’$.